# Call web service method from generic handler

Tags: asp.net, asmx, generic-handler

In my asp.net application I have web service `~/service.asmx` and generic handler `~/handler.ashx`. How can I call web service's method from the generic handler? For example, in web service I have `string SayHello(string name)` method. To call it I need to make a request to `/service.asmx/SayHello`. What I need is to call that when user requests the generic handler `/handler.ashx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add service reference (which will create a proxy class) and create an instance of `Webservice` proxy class and call this method. If web-service is located in your current web-app then you may instantiate that class and call method as we call the regular method.

Comment: In this case I need to manually parse url arguments to construct parameters to call web service method. Wanted to avoid it.

Comment: And yes, web service and handler are in the same web application.

Comment: @AndreyM. You want to call that service method in code (handler) then you have to pass string value. Does handler has any request parameter?

Comment: @ADV Actually, the web service method have more complex arguments, than simple string, special DTO objects. The handler should receive the same arguments, that would be passed to the web service, if I call it directly from browser. The browser script will care of it.

Comment: I want somehow pass HttpContext object with all data I got from client and allow to web service internals process them and call web service method.

Comment: @AndreyM. You may access HttpContext in web service method too.